# Simplify $2- {\frac{a\left(1-(\frac{1}{2a})\right)}{0.25}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Simplify:
$$2- {\frac{a\left(1-(\frac{1}{2a})\right)}{0.25}}$$

1. I removed the parenthesis by filling it in. I got: $a(\frac{-a}{2a}).$ I multiplied a with $2a= 2a^2.$ So now I have $2a^2\div 2a= a.$
2. Filling in a in the equation that I originally had gave me: $2- (\frac {a}{0.25}).$ To involve the $2$, I made: ${\frac{2(0.25)}{0.25}}  - (\frac{a}{0.25}).$
3. I calculated this so I got ${(2\times0.25)/0.25} =0.5$
4. Filling in gave me: $\frac{0.5-a}{0.25}= 2-a$

Apparently this is not correct. Can anyone point out where I went wrong? Please don't give me the answer to the question.

- Ok with help this is my second attempt:

1. Filling the parenthesis ~~Thank you, mvw~~ 1-$(\frac{1}{2a}) = (2a-\frac{1}{2a}) = 2a$ cancel out so I'm left with $-1.$
2. Filling in a in the equation that I originally had gave me: $2 - [a\times\frac{-1}{0.25}].$ $a$ times -1 is $-a$ $2- (\frac{-a}{0.25}).$
3. To involve the 2, I again made: $\left[\frac{2(0.25)}{0.25}\right] - (\frac{-a}{0.25}).$ Minus + minus = plus. So $a\div 0.25= 4a.$
4. This gave me: ${[2\times(0.25) \div 0.25] + 4a}.$ ~~~~ $(2 + 4a)$ or $(0.25 + 4a)$ or $(1 + 4a)$ If I divide $0.25$ by $0.25 = 1.$
5. $2 + 4a = 2(1+2a)$ or $(0.25 + 4a)$ or $(1+4a)$

Again incorrect. Can anyone help me with the solution?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Did you mean $\left(\frac{1}{2}a\right)$ or $\left(\frac{1}{2a}\right)$ in the innermost parenthesis?

Comment: the 2nd one is what I meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The innermost two terms give
$$
(1-(1/2a))=\frac{2a-1}{2a}
$$
Stopping to not spoil more.

Full go:
$$
2 - \{a(1-(1/2a)) /0.25\} = \\
$$
writing out the fractions
$$
2 - \left\{a \left(1-\frac{1}{2a}\right)\frac{1}{1/4}\right\} = \\
$$
Using the common denominator $2a$ for the fraction in the inner parentheses and using that division by a fraction is multiplication by its inverse
$$
2 - \left\{a \left(\frac{2a-1}{2a}\right)\frac{4}{1}\right\} = \\
$$
shortening the fraction by $a$, dropping the $1$ denominator
$$
2 - \frac{2a - 1}{2} \cdot 4 = \\
$$
now multiplying by $4/2 = 2$
$$
2 - 2(2a-1) = \\
$$
and adding the $2$'s
$$
4-4a = 4(1-a)
$$

Comment: Should I post this question again in order to get it answered? I don't know if people will still see my question since I posted it yesterday.

Comment: The answer in my book shows 4(1-a). Isn't that 4-4a? I didn't knew 0.25 could be written as 4/1, thank you.

Comment: Yes it is. Lemme check the other interpretation. And please check, if the formula to simplify is equal to that one in your book.

Comment: O wait I think I got it. If I mulitply the 2 I get: 2-4a+2= 4-4a =  4(1-a) Thanks! -2*-1 =2.

Comment: Yes, I got it wrong. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Check what you are dividing by $0.25$ - be careful about the brackets - and note that $0.25$ is different from $0.5$ or $\frac 12$